# How to copy node with all its children from an XML document to another one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have some C# code to open an XML document and to append the XML element to the selected node. However, I need to get copy of a bunch of nodes from one XML document to include them in another XML document.

How can I do this?

**my C# code**

```
    XmlDocument Formal_TemplateField = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDocument BuildMyGridView = new XmlDocument();
    Formal_TemplateField.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Formal_TemplateField.xml"));
    BuildMyGridView.Load(Server.MapPath("~/BuildMyGridView.xml"));

    XmlElement controls = (XmlElement)Formal_TemplateField.SelectSingleNode("controls");
    XmlElement Columns = BuildMyGridView.GetElementById("Columns");

    Columns.AppendChild(controls); //<--- error here
    BuildMyGridView.Save(Server.MapPath("~/BuildMyGridView.xml"));
```

This code gives me an error (System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.')!
What is wrong?

Comment: Columns is null. Can you debug and see if it is?

Comment: Also; you cannot append a node gathered from XML document A into XML Document B directly. Use XmlDocument.ImportNode() first, and try to append the output of this method

Comment: @OguzOzgul I found this and it has bunch of nodes as needed (XmlNodeList controls = Formal_TemplateField.GetElementsByTagName("controls");). but still searching how to append controls to Columns.

Comment: What will the end result be like? 1. `<Columns><controls>.....</controls></Columns>` or 2. `<Columns><Column><controls>.....</controls></Column><Column><controls>.....</controls></Column></Columns>`

Comment: @OguzOzgul I did as you mentioned (XmlDocument.ImportNode()) and it is good. as follows --> (XmlNode NEW_NOOD = BuildMyGridView.ImportNode(Formal_TemplateField.DocumentElement["controls"], true); BuildMyGridView.DocumentElement.AppendChild(NEW_NOOD);). However, I can't change this (BuildMyGridView.DocumentElement.AppendChild(NEW_NOOD);) to this (BuildMyGridView.DocumentElement["Columns"].AppendChild(NEW_NOOD);). So, the result comes at the end of the document, not at the specific node (["Columns"])

Comment: Do this: `Columns.AppendChild(NEW_NOOD);` In your source code, Columns is representing the <Columns> node if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and the code will be just like this.

**C#**

```
XmlDocument Formal_TemplateField = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument BuildMyGridView = new XmlDocument();

Formal_TemplateField.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Formal_TemplateField.xml"));
BuildMyGridView.Load(Server.MapPath("~/BuildMyGridView.xml"));

XmlNode NEW_NOOD = BuildMyGridView.ImportNode(Formal_TemplateField.DocumentElement["controls"], true);
BuildMyGridView.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Columns")[0].AppendChild(NEW_NOOD);

BuildMyGridView.Save(Server.MapPath("~/BuildMyGridView.xml"));
```